# XCode 3.2.5, iOS 4.2 - Why does the iPad Simulator launch instead of the iPhone Simulator?

Tags: iphone, xcode, simulator

I have an app that is iPhone only (Targeted Device Family == iPhone), Base SDK 4.2, iOS Deployment Target 4.0.

Once in a while, but pretty often, the target switch to iPad Simulator. Is this a bug ? I shouldn't even have this option in the target selection dropdown...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Thomas : I thinkg that you chosed 'iPhone only' on the wrong configuration of the target (ex : 'distribution' instead of 'debug'). If you choose 'iPhone' for the debug configuration, your app should never lanch in the iPad simulator.

To kkend0g187 : choose 'iPhone' for the "targeted device family" in the debug configuration of the target. Otherwise, you will come back to the wrong device not just when you run but when you clean the targets before running.

Answer (score 2):

In my eyes is the best way to work arround is to set up the Device in the Simulator under Devices. There you can also choose between iPhone with or without Retina Display.
Once Open, the Simulator-Device will stay.

cheers